# Processing a search-function at the server or at the SPA?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, single-page-application, mean

Hi fellow programmers!

I am currently working on a SPA project, where the main model class is a plain old User.

Example of the schema.

```
User = {'name': 'christopher', 'age': '21', 'nationality': 'Denmark'};
```

For my question, i don't seek any code or examples.

I am implementing a search-function for searching through all the users stored on the server.

So my application is going to serve the users containing whatever the user wrote in the search-field, after the user has hit submit on the search-button, and then i should decide following choices:

- Call a 'get-all-users'-request to the server, and then make the filtering in the SPA, after getting ALL users.

OR

- Implement this search-function at the server-side that filters everything and serves it in the result of the request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: depends on how many users there are.

Comment: Of course, let's say we have 10000 users.

Comment: then do it in the backend. There is a good chance your ui will freeze if you filter so many items synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until a couple of years ago, the general rule was to place as much logic as possible on the server side. Now, with better JS technology and browser engines more it is possible (and in some cases desirable) to place logic on the client side.

Pros for server-side logic:

- Security. Anyone can read your Javascript (even if it is minified)
- Performance. Browsers will go slower when you are dealing with large datasets.
- Browsers. You will have to deal with various numbers of browser. And although new js and css libraries has eliminated much of 'the old problems', there are a surprisingly large number of people still using old versions of IE.
- Scalability. You can increase your server(s) processing capabilities (especially if it is virtual), but you can not make your user's browsers go faster.

Pros for client-side logic:

- Better user experience as you have better responsiveness (do not need a round trip over the network for every interaction) and better/rich user interfaces (E.g. Angular.js with bootstrap)
- Scalability, as the users' browsers are doing all the work it saves your server processing.
- Lower network cost, as you do not have to send the same amount of data.

These are just from the top of my head. In your case, I think I would have placed as much logic as possible on the server side. You are less likely to freeze the browsers with heavy data processing and you could increase you servers capabilities if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, you shouldn't transfer data over the network unless you have to. In your case, getting all users when your customer only wanted a small subset would be a terrible misuse of their bandwidth.